# Retrieve one value from a list of dicts based on another value in the dict

Tags: python, json, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary created from a JSON document:

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "hourly": 1
  }
    }
    ,
"hourly_forecast": [
    {
    "FCTTIME": {
    "hour": "22","hour_padded": "22","min": "00","min_unpadded": "0","sec": "0","year": "2017","mon": "3","mon_padded": "03","mon_abbrev": "Mar","mday": "8","mday_padded": "08","yday": "66","isdst": "0","epoch": "1489028400","pretty": "10:00 PM EST on March 08, 2017","civil": "10:00 PM","month_name": "March","month_name_abbrev": "Mar","weekday_name": "Wednesday","weekday_name_night": "Wednesday Night","weekday_name_abbrev": "Wed","weekday_name_unlang": "Wednesday","weekday_name_night_unlang": "Wednesday Night","ampm": "PM","tz": "","age": "","UTCDATE": ""
    },
    "temp": {"english": "50", "metric": "10"},
    "dewpoint": {"english": "20", "metric": "-7"},
    "condition": "Partly Cloudy",
    "icon": "partlycloudy",
    "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_partlycloudy.gif",
    "fctcode": "2",
    "sky": "6",
    "wspd": {"english": "29", "metric": "47"},
    "wdir": {"dir": "W", "degrees": "262"},
    "wx": "Clear/Wind",
    "uvi": "0",
    "humidity": "30",
    "windchill": {"english": "-9999", "metric": "-9999"},
    "heatindex": {"english": "-9999", "metric": "-9999"},
    "feelslike": {"english": "50", "metric": "10"},
    "qpf": {"english": "0.0", "metric": "0"},
    "snow": {"english": "0.0", "metric": "0"},
    "pop": "0",
    "mslp": {"english": "30.01", "metric": "1016"}
    }
    ,
    {
    "FCTTIME": {
    "hour": "23","hour_padded": "23","min": "00","min_unpadded": "0","sec": "0","year": "2017","mon": "3","mon_padded": "03","mon_abbrev": "Mar","mday": "8","mday_padded": "08","yday": "66","isdst": "0","epoch": "1489032000","pretty": "11:00 PM EST on March 08, 2017","civil": "11:00 PM","month_name": "March","month_name_abbrev": "Mar","weekday_name": "Wednesday","weekday_name_night": "Wednesday Night","weekday_name_abbrev": "Wed","weekday_name_unlang": "Wednesday","weekday_name_night_unlang": "Wednesday Night","ampm": "PM","tz": "","age": "","UTCDATE": ""
    },
    "temp": {"english": "49", "metric": "9"},
    "dewpoint": {"english": "20", "metric": "-7"},
    "condition": "Partly Cloudy",
    "icon": "partlycloudy",
    "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_partlycloudy.gif",
    "fctcode": "2",
    "sky": "5",
    "wspd": {"english": "24", "metric": "39"},
    "wdir": {"dir": "W", "degrees": "263"},
    "wx": "Clear/Wind",
    "uvi": "0",
    "humidity": "32",
    "windchill": {"english": "-9999", "metric": "-9999"},
    "heatindex": {"english": "-9999", "metric": "-9999"},
    "feelslike": {"english": "49", "metric": "9"},
    "qpf": {"english": "0.0", "metric": "0"},
    "snow": {"english": "0.0", "metric": "0"},
    "pop": "0",
    "mslp": {"english": "30.02", "metric": "1017"}
    }
```

With this data, I want to get the 'temp' value from the first dictionary in the 'hourly_forecast' list whose 'hour' is '22'.

I know I could use the code below to get the first element:

```
j_hour['hourly_forecast'][0]['temp']['english']
```

... but this data always changes based on the time I retrieve it, so if it was 1 PM it would be `"hour": "13"` first up.

Basically I need help with pulling the 'temp' data based on the 'hour' value with a list that is always changing, so I can't just pull it based on element sequence.

To sum it up, I'm stuck printing the 'temp' key from the 'hour' I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to approach this is to narrow your search down step by step until you get just the piece of information you're looking for.

First, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get all the english temperatures, regardless of hour:

```
>>> [d['temp']['english'] for d in j_hour['hourly_forecast']]
['50', '49', ...]
```

Then restrict it to cases where the hour is '22':

```
>>> [d['temp']['english'] for d in j_hour['hourly_forecast']
...                       if d['FCTTIME']['hour'] == '22']
['50']
```

Now you've got the temperature you want, wrapped in a list. If you convert the list comprehension to a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) by replacing the brackets `[]` with parentheses `()`, you can call [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on it to get the first (and only, in this case) item:

```
>>> next(d['temp']['english'] for d in j_hour['hourly_forecast']
...                           if d['FCTTIME']['hour'] == '22')
'50'
```

*... et voilà!*

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for! If you don't mind mind me asking how would I add a second hour to your function? I've never used generator expressions before and I got     `next(d['temp']['english'] for d in j_hour['hourly_forecast'] if d['FCTTIME']['hour'] == '22', '21')
        ^
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument`

Comment: `next(f['temp']['english'] for f in j_hour['hourly_forecast'] if f["FCTTIME"]['hour'] in ('21', '22'))` ... note that if more than one dictionary matches, `next()` will only return the first. If you want all matching results, go back to a listcomp and forget about `next()`, e.g. `[f['temp']['english'] for f in j_hour['hourly_forecast'] if f["FCTTIME"]['hour'] in ('21', '22')]`

Comment: Apart from using `==` when `in` is the right operator for testing membership in the collection `('21', '22')`, the syntax error you got was because you didn't wrap `'22', '21'` in parentheses – which meant that Python couldn't easily tell whether it was part of the genexp, or a second argument to `next()` ... i.e. `next(<genexp>, '21')`.

Comment: Yes thank you so much. The `next(f['temp']['english'] for f in j_hour['hourly_forecast'] if f["FCTTIME"]['hour'] in ('21', '22'))` was only printing one value so I used the second one and for any hour that was above 12 (the entire json data had 48 hours worth so hours were repeated) and I used `hours_48 = [f['temp']['english'] for f in j_hour['hourly_forecast'] if f["FCTTIME"]['hour'] in ('4', '7')]

hours_24 = hours_48[:-2]` to remove the last two values since I only wanted it for one day. All is well now! Thank you